# J query - fade between pages and preload page with text

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I have just started using JQUERY and have run into a problem. I want to have a simple pre-load page with text that waits for the site to load. I also want to have JQUERY fades between pages.

I only want the text to appear when the page loads for the first time, not between nav links on the page. My code works when I load the page but it also displays the text between the nav links.

Thanks for any help, hope it makes sense

JQuery

```
$(window).load(function() {
$(".loader").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");       
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(2000);
});
    $('#link').click(function(){
        $("body").css("display", "none");
        $("body").fadeIn(2000);

});
```

CSS

```
.loader {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background-color: black;
}

#load_text{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

HTML

```
<body>   
<div class="loader">
    <h1 id = "load_text">THIS IS A BIG HEADING</h1>
</div>

<div class = "jumbotron">
    <div id = "container">
                <a href = "index.html" id = "link" > <h1>LINK</h1></a>
                <a href = "second page.html" id = "link"> <h1>LINK2</h1></a>     
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

---

Thanks for your help I tried your suggestion but I cant get it to work.
Here is the code.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
                // check cookie
    var visited = $.cookie("visited")

    if (visited == null) {   

        $(".loader").css("display", "inline");
        $(".loader").fadeOut(2000);
        $.cookie('visited', 'yes'); 
        alert($.cookie("visited"));         
    }

$(window).unload(function () {
    // Remove the cookie
    $.cookie("visited", null);
});      


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Store a variable (as a cookie, for example) which will indicate if the page loads for the first time or not. 
Perform a check before fading function, and if the page is loaded for the first time, do fade, else – do nothing.

Comment: I tried storing a cookie variable but cant get it to work, would you be able to help. See above.

Comment: You are trying to use $.cookie, which is a function from a jquery plugin. Did you connect that plugin?